# increase the number of defaulters in a sample

Tags: r, sample, sampling

I have a banking dataset which has 5% defaulters and the rest are good( non-defaulters).

I want to create a sample which has 30% defaulters , 70% non-defaulters.

Assuming my dataset is data and it has a column named "default" signifying 0 or 1, how do i get a sample with 30% default, 70% non-default given that my original dataset has only 5% default.

Can some one please provide the R code. That would be great.
I tried the following to get 100 random samples with replacement

```
data[sample(1:nrow(data),size=100,replace=TRUE),]
```

But how do i ensure that I get that the split is 30%,70%?

Answer (score 0):

`sample` has an option `prob` that represents a vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled. So you could use `prob=c(0.3,0.7)` as a parameter to `sample`.

For example

```
sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3,0.7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume `df` is your dataframe and `default` is the column indicating who defaults.

To sample without replacement:

```
df[c(sample(which(df$default),30), sample(which(!df$default),70)),]
```

To sample with replacement (i.e., possibly duplicating records):

```
df[c(sample(which(df$default),30,TRUE), sample(which(!df$default),70,TRUE)),]
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to specify an exact number of defaulters and non-defaulters, you can specify a sampling probability for each row:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(default=rbinom(250,1,.5), y=rnorm(250))

n <- 100 # could be any number, but closer you get to nrow(df) the less the weights matters
s <- sample(seq_along(df$default), n, prob=ifelse(df$default, .3, .7))
table(df$default[s])
#
#  0  1 
# 61 39 

n <- 150 # could be any number, but closer you get to nrow(df) the less the weights matters
s <- sample(seq_along(df$default), n, prob=ifelse(df$default, .3, .7))
table(df$default[s])
#
#  0  1 
# 97 53
```